# js grid templated rows and columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsgrid

can i bind jsgrid with predefined columns in html table

```
<table id="MapDetails">
   <thead>
       <th>...
       <th>..
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
 </table>
```

So, now can i do something like this?

```
$("#MapDetails").jsGrid({
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",

        inserting: true,
        editing: true,
        sorting: true,
        paging: true

    });
```

AND in addition to above then define an itemTemplate for rows and finally able to sort, page, edit and bind to drop-down list etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, jsGrid cannot be defined on top of predefined table markup. All the markup will be rendered by the plugin.
Just declare an empty element and initialize jsGrid on top providing configuration.

```
<div id="jsGrid"></div>

<script>
    $("#jsGrid").jsGrid({
        // your configuration
    });
</script>
```

Checkout the getting started [guide](http://js-grid.com/getting-started/).